How to make a "gradual" text function in C++?
So, I wanted to make a text adventure in C++, and I wanted to create a cool function that allowed the text to be displayed letter-by-letter gradually, like in movies.
The issue is that my code isn't displaying it one letter at a time, but waiting and then displaying it all at once, defeating the whole purpose.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void cool_text(std::string text) {
    for (char letter: text) {
        std::cout << letter;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

    }
}

int main() {
    cool_text("Programing");
}

However, if I were to write line 7 like so...
std::cout << letter << std::endl;

...then it displays it letter-by-letter, but even that isn't consistent.
How should I go about this? Any help appreciated. (If it helps, I'm using an online editor on a Chromebook.)

Try changing std::cout << letter; to std::cout << letter << std::flush;.

c++ force std::cout flush (print to screen)

@user12002570 That's just part of the problem. See "even that isn't consistent".

This question is similar to: c++ force std::cout flush (print to screen). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@phuclv It's different because it doesn't involve the inconsistent timings mentioned in the Q: "even that isn't consistent".

The output is buffered and usually won't be displayed until you output a newline. You can however force it out using std::flush:
std::cout << letter << std::flush;


std::cout << letter << std::endl; ...then it displays it letter-by-letter, but even that isn't consistent.

std::endl is a combination of \n + std::flush and if that's not consistent you could replace sleep_for with sleep_until with a time point that you add 100ms to in every iteration:
void cool_text(const std::string& text) {
    auto tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(char letter : text) {
        std::cout << letter << std::flush;
        tp += std::chrono::milliseconds(100);
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp);
    }
}

This should make it a bit more consistent.

This worked excellently! Made the output way more consistent. Thank you.

@Favor You're welcome! I'm glad it helped!

Thank you again, though I do have to access, how come you used a constant reference to the text parameter instead of just the parameter?

@Favor Taking the parameter "by value" (as you do) is often good, when it's a very small amout of data that needs to be passed. A std::string is a complex thing. It's rarely less than 16 or 32 bytes even if you store just one character in it. If your question had revealed that you use C++17 or later, then I'd use std::string_view instead, and I would have taken it by value, because optimizations favor string_views in this context.
